# Accessing database objects in Django form cleaner

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there a way to access the database object from the django form cleaner? Or at least the URL to which the form data was posted? If I can get the URL, I can query for the database object.

My use case is that, I have a form that should raise an error if the database object from which the form was generated is in some particular state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - take a look at `self.instance` from inside your form's `clean` method.